# sending data from html form to mongodb database

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, database, mongodb

Im trying to send data to a local mongo database that i've got, but im not entirely sure why its not sending anything. 
I'd like to send the form data to the database. The idea is that its meant to send the form data over to the mongo database to be stored under the fields from the register.

Comment: You need to narrow down where it fails. Start with examining the POST request in the browser's dev tools.

Comment: Your Express controller for the route '/newtask' doesn't seem to have a logic for saving(inserting) data. It only has `findOne()`. You should include `insert()` in order to save the data from the client.

Comment: @ChrisG I tried checking after i signed the form and pressed the button but nothing new appears in the network section

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing read or write operation in control.js, your mongo connection `mongoose.connection()` should be in control.js and it seems you are not using the url to connect to mongodb.
And what is the output in control.js `console.log(htask);`

And if you would like to find one doc, if found return the doc if not found add one doc, you can use `{upsert:true,returnNewDocument:true}` in options.